# How to save some specific items from a list? Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list which is like this below:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "firstName": "Thomas",
            "lastName": "Papioanou",
            "userID": 238,
            "month": 5,
            "year": 2022,
            "cardBillsTotal": [
                {
                    "serial": "884221337251",
                    "value": 1.0450,
                    "vat": 0.2508,
                    "total": 1.2958,
                    "energy": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Thomas",
            "lastName": "Papioanou",
            "userID": 238,
            "month": 6,
            "year": 2022,
            "cardBillsTotal": [
                {
                    "serial": "884221337251",
                    "value": 3.4034,
                    "vat": 0.8168,
                    "total": 4.2202,
                    "energy": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Thomas",
            "lastName": "Papioanou",
            "userID": 238,
            "month": 7,
            "year": 2022,
            "cardBillsTotal": [
                {
                    "serial": "884221337251",
                    "value": 2.0900,
                    "vat": 0.5016,
                    "total": 2.5916,
                    "energy": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Thomas",
            "lastName": "Papioanou",
            "userID": 238,
            "month": 5,
            "year": 2022,
            "cardBillsTotal": [
                {
                    "serial": "941368618045",
                    "value": 2.2884,
                    "vat": 0.5492,
                    "total": 2.8376,
                    "energy": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Thomas",
            "lastName": "Papioanou",
            "userID": 238,
            "month": 6,
            "year": 2022,
            "cardBillsTotal": [
                {
                    "serial": "941368618045",
                    "value": 1.1083,
                    "vat": 0.2660,
                    "total": 1.3743,
                    "energy": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "count": 5
}
```

If month = 5 I want to store the bracket '[cardBillsTotal]', how can I do that?

Here is my request and code if you needed:

```
Future<List<Evsebillall>> fetchall() async {
    String? token = await this.storage.read(key: "token");
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + (token ?? ""),
    };
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        this.serverIP + ':' + this.serverPort +
            '/user/contractedChargeTransactionsList?page=1&limit=10'),
        headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      setState(() {
        cardBillsall = jsonDecode(response.body)["results"] as List;
        print(cardBillsall);
        var result = cardBillsall.map((e) => Evsebillall.fromJson(e)).toList();
        print (data);
      });
      return cardBillsall.map((e) => Evsebillall.fromJson(e)).toList();
    }
    else{
      throw Exception('Failed to load Bills');
    }
  }
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work out:

```
var data = cardBillsall.map((e) => e["month"]=5).toList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = cardBillsall.where((element) => element["month"]== 5).toList();

var cardBillsTotalList = [];
for (var item in data) {
  cardBillsTotalList.addAll(item['cardBillsTotal'] as List);
}
```

if you print `cardBillsTotalList` you will get this:

```
print("cardBillsTotalList =$cardBillsTotalList");  //cardBillsTotalList =[{serial: 884221337251, value: 1.045, vat: 0.2508, total: 1.2958, energy: 0}, {serial: 941368618045, value: 2.2884, vat: 0.5492, total: 2.8376, energy: 0}]
```

Comment: the resualt is:

I/flutter (25208): [true, false, false, true, false]

If true I want to store the bracket '[cardBillsTotal]

Comment: I used `where` not `map`, are you sure you copy my answer correctly?

Comment: and how can i store all 'total' which is inside this bracket?

Comment: where do you want to save it? you want me to show you how to access to inside the bracket?

Comment: i have the data that you showed me, now these data if you see they have in this case 2 'total' : total: 1.2958 total: 2.8376 ,  how can i store these totals somewhere?

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. you need ["total"] or ["cardBillsTotal"]?